# Wrong in counting real number

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

I know that real number is uncountable,the same as the closed interval [0,1].However,I don't know what is wrong with my method of counting numbers in [0,1]:

0.1,0.2…0.9

0.01,0.02…0.99

0.01,0.02,…0.999

....

Can anyone tell me what'wrong with it?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are merely counting *rational* numbers, not all real numbers between $0$ and $1$. The problem with the real numbers is that from *any* list of real numbers, using Cantor's diagonal argument, one can show that there exists a real number that is not in that list. This is why the real numbers are uncountable.

Have fun reading this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Hope that helps,

Comment: and even not all rationals, just with denominator $2^a5^b$.

Comment: I know what you mean thanks.

Comment: Now I know what is called countable set.That means that you devise a method to count with which every element can be placed in a particular position n.

Comment: @89085731 : Yes, exactly. The "method of counting" would be the bijection between your countable set $S$ and the set of positive integers $\mathbb N$, and if you count the elements by $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n, \dots \}$, then the bijection is $i \mapsto x_i$. By the way, if the answer I gave you answers your question you should click on the check button under the downvote button.

Answer (score 1):

When does your enumeration reach pi?  Or Sqrt(2)?  Or even 1/13?  It doesn't.

Comment: $\pi \notin [0,1]$, nor does $\sqrt 2$. But you're right about $\frac 1{13}$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: true, but he could ask about $\pi -3$ and $\sqrt 2 -1$

Comment: Sure, I was just mentioning.